# how to install or user Angular 2 in Codeigniter 3

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, codeigniter

i currently running Codeigniter 3x i have use and learn this for a month and wanna start learn JS framework but i do not know how to install/Use Angular in Codeigniter ? is it good to use Angular in Codeigniter ? if it good to use then it is my Directory.

```
Codeignter_Project/
------------------|application
------------------|assets
------------------------|bootstrap_3.3.7
------------------------|jquery_3.1.0
------------------------|my_lib
------------------------|nicescrol_3.6.8
------------------|system
------------------|application
------------------|index.php
```

is there any1 have use Angular in Codeigniter 3x please share some experience

Thank in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

1. At first, try to complete Angular JS basics. Otherwise, it will be difficult for you to understand the execution flow.
2. Yes, it's a good idea. You can use Angular JS with codeigniter.

**How to install it**

1. Include angular js inside head using their cdn or keep it inside your assets folder & include it like all other scripts.
2. Then define ng-app, ng-model, ng-bind etc inside your views & you will get your desired output.

Comment: thz and does it conflicts with bootstrap/jquery or not ? Or it is like React that need to download react- bootstrap ? Coz I see react-bootstrap not full feature of bootstrap ? Or in angular can just link rel as normal ? Coz I still need them before I can make clean code in angular.